# gridview paging problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i m using an gridview in which pagingsize is 5 when the next page is clicked it returns empty data. but actually it has 12 datas.im using sql as back end and asp.net c# and the data r calculated at the run time and displayed. 
im using this code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_attendancereports"  BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#DBDBDA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Grid" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7E7E7C" Width="700px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_attendancereports_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5"  >
```

Comment: your code seems to OK, you need to check in PageIndexChanging event, your datatable, weather it is empty or have data?

Comment: @Anand, have you check datatable data here, you can put break point and check datatable (dt) rows

Comment: @Anand; If the problem has been resolved, you should mark the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to rebind in page index changing event like

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DataTable dt = GetAllCity();// you need to get here again data from database or from some other sources as you have, to populate your gridview properly
    GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: protected void GridView_attendancereports_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
       
        GridView_attendancereports.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       GridView_attendancereports.DataSource = dt;
        GridView_attendancereports.DataBind();
    }
im using this code and here , only first page is displayed when 2 is clicked it display empty field

Comment: Are you populating the data in variable dt... EVEN DURING POST BACK... or are you populating the dt only during the initial load.

Comment: your code seems to OK, you need to check in PageIndexChanging event, your datatable, weather it is empty or have data?

Comment: protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
it also dosent work.
yes,i m populating the data in the variable dt.

Comment: hi king,
dt variable is used during postback also

Comment: @Anand, have you check datatable data here, you can put break point and check datatable (dt) rows

Comment: hi akhtar'
dt dosnt return any data when break point is used to trace it when second page is bclicked

Answer (score 1):

try rebinding to your datasource.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: your comment on something almost three years old is almost as useless as my original answer. i suspect that most viewers of this page will ignore this and look at the answer above, which is far more helpful and has good quality comments - you should do the same.